# How do I fix an error with l3backend-pdftex.def in Texmaker

Tags: miktex, windows

Here is what I believe relevant to my problem (taken from the log file of **Texmaker**):
.......................................................

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.10.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.4.18) 27 NOV 2023 12:10
.
.
.

LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1

L3 programming layer <2023-03-30>
(C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdftex.def

File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-11-09 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)

! LaTeX Error: Mismatched LaTeX support files detected.

(LaTeX) Loading 'l3backend-pdftex.def' aborted!

(LaTeX)

(LaTeX) The L3 programming layer in the LaTeX format

(LaTeX) is dated 2023-03-30, but in your TeX tree the files require

(LaTeX) at least 2023-10-10.

For immediate help type H <return>.

...

l.44 }


The most likely causes are:

- A recent format generation failed;

- A stray format file in the user tree which needs to be removed or rebuilt;

- You are running a manually installed version of l3backend-pdftex.def

which is incompatible with the version in LaTeX.

LaTeX will abort loading the incompatible support files but this may lead to

later errors. Please ensure that your LaTeX format is correctly regenerated.
```

........................................................

One answer that should have worked was given by Frank Mittelbach.  However the `fmtutil` function no longer exists in my latest release of MiKTeX.

I looked at trying:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64>l3build install --full
```

l3build: security risk: running with elevated privileges
Error: Cannot find configuration build.lua

Comment: You can rebuild formats in the miktex console.

Comment: How can I rebuild a format(s) that will fix the problem